# Casting object to long

Tags: c#, .net, casting

Unfortunately, in our (legacy) code base there is a property of a class that has type `object` and can be either a `int` or a `long`.

When trying to cast it to a long like this:

`long id = (long) dBLockTabellenOptionen.Id;`

I get the following exception:

> Exception: Fehler in DoOneWorkRound:
>   Specified cast is not valid.                                                                                                          Specified cast is not valid. ->   Specified cast is not valid.
>   --- Exception Liste ---
>   System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

How can I savely cast it to a `long` without getting an exception?

**Disclaimer:** I know, that this property is a big smell but at this moment, the refactoring of it would be too much and since this application is going to get rewritten soon we will do it right then

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but you can give it a try `if (dBLockTabellenOptionen.Id is long)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`long id = Convert.ToInt64(dBlockTabellenOptionen.Id);` should do the trick.

Comment: Only recommendation I can add to this, is to wrap it in a try/catch block to avoid runtime errors, if there is a chance that the object coming in isn't convertible to a long.

Answer (score -2):

Have you try to use Try.Parse

```
long bigInteger = 0;
long.TryParse(dBLockTabellenOptionen.Id, out bigInteger);
```

Comment: No. Id is an `object`, not a `string`.

Comment: a `long` named `bigInteger`?